# Microwave tray tevilah

Tags: tevilas-keilim-dipping, appliances

Does you need to tovel the glass plate from a microwave in a  mikvah, and do you need a Bracha?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is made out of glass and many times the actual food will directly touch the plate as yydl indicated, You should tovel  with a b’racha. (S.A. Y.D. 120:1)

Answer (score 4):

The Star-K says tovel WITHOUT a beracha.

http://www.star-k.org/kashrus/kk-containers-tevilasguide.htm

Answer (score 3):

As always, for a matter of practical *halacha*, [CYLOR](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/CYLOR). But AFAIK something that doesn't touch food does not require *t'vila*.

Comment: It's hard to say it never touches food. I know many who use microwave for e.g. a potato, in which case it does touch...

Answer (score 1):

The Kof-K [says](https://www.kof-k.org/articles/040108090413W-3%20Tevilas%20Keilim.pdf) the tray doesn't need to be toveled if it doesn't touch the food.

> Microwave Oven Tray- A glass microwave oven tray does not require tevilah if no food
>   actually touches the glass. If food is placed directly on the glass piece then the tray
>   should be toveled with a beracha.

This part is speculation: The Star-K [psak](http://www.star-k.org/kashrus/kk-containers-tevilasguide.htm) to tovel without a bracha might be a more general psak to cover both people that use the tray touching the food and people that do not. People that use tray touching the food would need to tovel with a bracha, but those that don't use the tray touching the food would not have to tovel at all. The Star-K might be recommending to tovel without a bracha in order to cover both cases. [CYLOR](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/CYLOR)