# Does a table require tevila?

Tags: halacha, tevilas-keilim-dipping, glass

Does a table need to be *toiveled* if it is made of glass? It doesn't seem to be common practice, but I would think it's a כלי אכילה.

Comment: Do you eat off the table?

Comment: http://www.yahadoot.net/item.asp?id=552&cid=16

Comment: @Ploni Please CMIIAW but I think if you put food down on the table (e.g. a bunch of bananas), that would be an issue...

Comment: @Loewian If you have box with some metal pens in it and you put the food down on top of the pens that would also be a problem? Putting the food down on it doesn't make it a כלי אכילה.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5979/microwave-tray-tevilah

Comment: @Ploni as opposed to a pot?

Comment: @Loewian Yes. The pot is used to prepare the food, to serve it. Putting the food down on a surface doesn't mean it's preparing the food.

Comment: @Ploni Even where the surface was designed for putting food down upon?

Comment: @Loewian I don't think so.

Comment: @Ploni From the discussions about fridge shelves, I think it sounds like it would be a problem. (See e.g. https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.kof-k.org%2Farticles%2F040108090413W-3%2520Tevilas%2520Keilim.pdf

Comment: @Ploni many times when people pass out bread on shabbos they put it directly on the table, and a tablecloth may be considered battel to the table.

Comment: @Ploni the box with pens will never be considered כלי אכילה (unless its specifically designated for food) because food isn't it's primary use. A tables primary use can very often be for food.

Comment: @Eliyahu editing the comments about bread and primary vs. secondary usage into the question would help motivate it more.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Kof-K](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.kof-k.org%2Farticles%2F040108090413W-3%2520Tevilas%2520Keilim.pdf), citing the *Shalmei Moed* (p. 556), a table does not require *tevila* even if food is placed directly on it.

Comment: What's the reason?